# How to remove unicode characters without removing parts of text

Tags: python-3.x, character-encoding

I am trying to do an N-gram analysis on an ancient language that does not have modern orthography and I am running into a problem of encoding.

The orthography looks like the following
[image]

It is contained in a Docx document and I use the following code to retrieve it

```
Text    = docx2txt.process(Corpus)
        print(Text)
```

When I put it into a dictionary it spits out the following

```
"daniel.mahabi": {"xq\u2019xucubaquibms.xqui\u00e7i\ua72dih": 1.0},
```

I can partially resolve this with the following code

```
Text    = docx2txt.process(Corpus)
        Text    = Text.encode("ascii", "ignore")
        Text    = Text.decode()
```

However upon doing that it also removes parts of the text.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: What's your expected output? Either you get Unicode characters or you remove them. In your case, the NLP should be able to handle Unicode data.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].